# How to enable click sorting on count distinct column

Tags: views, 8

I have a table view with a relationship to nodes associated with a taxonomy. Using aggregation, I have a column that lists a distinct count for the number of node references to the given taxonomy term. (see screen shot)

I was able to add a default sort by this count column, but I am unable to enable click sorting on the column. I'm not sure why one would work without the other... any suggestions?

For reference, here are some screen shots:

[image: Configuration for the view, showing the relationship and aggregation]

[image: The resulting view, by default sorted by count, but not sortable on the distinct count]

[image: Table settings showing that the table cannot be click sortable on the distinct count]